# Using pipe when executing command in perl

Tags: perl, pipe

I am trying to use following command in perl but it giving me error

```
system("zcat myfile.gz | wc > abc.txt");
```

But when i run this I am getting error 
syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Even if I remove `>abc.txt` I am still getting error.

Can we use pipe with system command?

Here are error details:

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
sh: -c: line 1: ` | wc '
```

Comment: Works for me. What are the actual filenames?

Comment: I am trying to give system("zcat myfile.gz | wc"); but its not working .

Comment: works for me too on solaris.

Comment: Actually its myfile*.gz and there is only one file matching it

Comment: hmmm but I am getting same error again..is there any way to debug this?

Comment: I suppose you have tried that exact command on the command line and it works?

Comment: yes it works prefect on command line :(

Comment: Note that this call uses `/bin/sh -c` for the shell, which might not be the same one you normally use.  Perhaps try it on that one?

Comment: @dan1111 can u explain a bit more what should I try?

Comment: run `/bin/sh` from the command line and then try the command. Is it the same?

Comment: @dan111 yes its same even after running /bin/sh

Answer (score 5):

Next time, test your demo program to make sure it actually exhibits the behaviour you said it does. You actually ran something closer to

```
while (my $file_name = <>) {
   system("zcat $file_name | wc > abc.txt");
}
```

There are two errors in that:

- You didn't remove the trailing newline, so the shell was trying to execute

  ```
  zcat def.gz
   | wc >abc.txt
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  zcat def.gz | wc >abc.txt
  ```
- You didn't transform the file name into a shell literal before emdedding it your command.

  Consider what would happen if the file name contained a space. You would be executing

  ```
  zcat def ghi.gz | wc >abc.txt
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  zcat 'def ghi.gz' | wc >abc.txt
  ```

Solution:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

while (my $file_name = <>) {
   chomp($file_name);
   system("zcat -- ".shell_quote($file_name)." | wc > abc.txt");
}
```

Comment: why you have used zcat -- in system call

Comment: In case the file names starts with a "`-`".

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected:

```
perl -lne 'system("cat *.java|wc");'
```

Something odd with your filename, maybe.

You could check the interpolation of your shell like this:

```
my @file = `ls -1 myfile*.gz`;chomp(@files);
print join("\n",@files);
```

There are other possibilites to execute in perl, like backtick, open with |, qx.

If you are trouble with filenames, you could get the filenames by yourself and call the system in a specific way to avoid executing shell: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch19_07.htm

> If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is /bin/sh -c on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and passed directly to execvp , which is more efficient.

Comment: what do u mean by checking  interpolation of your shell like this:

Comment: I am newbie in perl , can u provide me example how to achieve this using open or backtick or qx

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when trying to use backticks to execute a pipeline that included a `cut -d \|` command. Turns out I had to double escape the pipe character eg `cut -d \\|`